# couldn't infer template argument - do I need to use explicit template parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

```
template <int I, typename T> struct Wrap {
  T internal;
};

template <int I, typename T>
Wrap<I, T> DoStuff(int z) { return Wrap<I, T>{(T)z}; }

class Wrapped {
public:
// Working
  Wrap<1, int> GetInt() { return DoStuff<1, int>(1); }
  Wrap<2, long> GetLong() { return DoStuff<2, long>(2); }

// Not working
  Wrap<3, char> GetChar() { return DoStuff(3); }
};
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##fY7BisIwFEX3@Yq7TKEi1Z0VNyNIYZjNFLqOmdgpxjSkrwy29NtrEpRxQGb3SO4590prF1ILU88zqYvVghS2jSEUKehqlREXhXKHjlwvCZUTFiMDSviQckbonE05Y//BLFBb/@Y9@/aT@tOJh9SQYIRT1DuD38jIy2SYckyM@WFdF7@s@vK1tj/qRm7YcomqdefG1H5JJLM07NnhoKgwxJ/E98JHgmdJUN@xVQrdmjpy7/54BT4yfBXJUP7REn7@DlinkN/CRdObP16Y@DoKpnyebw)

Why is the third function failing to resolve the template argument? I thought the compiler would try to match the template definition with the return type of the function. Is this working in c++14 or any newer versions?

Comment: Return types never participate in overload resolution or in template argument deduction.

Comment: This will not work in newer C++ versions either.  The compiler must figure out which `DoStuff` to call **before** it can figure out how to convert that function's return value to `GetChar`'s return value.

Comment: You can avoid *some* repetition in C++14 by using `auto` for the return type. You'd still need to resolve `DoStuff` correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deduction doesn't use return value... *"Except"* for converting operator.

So you might create a class which convert to any `Wrap<I, T>`:

```
struct ToWrap
{
    int n;

    template <int I, typename T>
    operator Wrap<I, T>() const { return Wrap<I, T>{T(n)}; }
};

ToWrap DoStuff(int z) {
    return ToWrap{z};
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1jxjdjxrb)

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you specified return type to be `Wrap<3, char>` doesn't mean that you cannot create other parametrized `Wrap`-type objects inside `GetChar()`. You need to specify the template arguments, as `DoStuff(3)` is just a function call that does not resolve either `I` or `T`.